Create CSV file from converting Json Output into CSV either using Pandas or CSV/Json Library in Django
I am struggling to figure out how to get my already made Json output and also create a csv file from that output. For more clarification, I have created a json file by using write, but I am unsure on how to also create a CSV file during the same process. Maybe I am just not inputting the CSV code in the correct area, or if Django needs some other form of method to process that request.
utils.py
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv
import urllib.parse

def get_ip_list_json() -> dict:

    json_response = {
        "version": "",
        "description": "",
        "objects": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "id": "",
                "description": "",
                "ranges": ["2.2.2.2"],
            },
        ],
    }

    group_map = {}

    for ip in BlockedList.objects.filter(
        Q(end_date__isnull=True) | Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now())
    ).select_related("group"):
        group_id = str(ip.group.id)
        if group_id not in group_map:
            group_map[group_id] = {
                "name": ip.group.name,
                "id": ip.group.group_id,
                "description": ip.group.description,
                "ranges": [],
            }
        group_map[group_id]["ranges"].append(ip.address)

    json_response["objects"] = list(group_map.values())
    return json_response


Edit:
This is how I have used the solution below done by Nayem, just changed some parts to personalize but should give the same output.
def create_ip_file():
    try:
        base_dir = ""
        csv_filename = ""

        csv_full_path = os.path.join(base_dir, csv_filename)

        # Query all entries in the BlockedList
        blockedlist = BlockedList.objects.all()
        data_for_csv = []
        for obj in blockedlist:
            # Format the end date to dd/mm/yyyy
            formatted_end_date = obj.end_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            # URL encode the reason to replace any commas with special characters
            encoded_reason = urllib.parse.quote(obj.reason)
            # Append the data to the list for CSV conversion
            data_for_csv.append({
                "NetworkAddress": obj.address,
                "Group": obj.group,
                "Reason": encoded_reason,
                "Expiry": formatted_end_date
                })

        # Convert the list to a DataFrame using pandas
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_csv)

        # Create the CSV file from the DataFrame
        df.to_csv(csv_full_path, index=False)

    except Exception as e:
        # Print any exceptions that occur
        print(e)


I suspect it is simply writing them to a location you do not know.  How are you launching the script?  What is the "current directory" when you launch it?  Have you searched for those files?

Simple.
Generate the JSON data-> Write the JSON data to a file -> Convert the JSON data to a Pandas DataFrame -> Write the DataFrame to a CSV file.
import json
import os
import pandas as pd

from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Q
from api.models import BlockedList

def get_ip_list_json() -> dict:

    json_response = {
        "version": "",
        "description": "",
        "objects": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "id": "",
                "description": "",
                "ranges": ["2.2.2.2"],
            },
        ],
    }

    group_map = {}

    for ip in BlockedList.objects.filter(
        Q(end_date__isnull=True) | Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now())
    ).select_related("group"):
        group_id = str(ip.group.id)
        if group_id not in group_map:
            group_map[group_id] = {
                "name": ip.group.name,
                "id": ip.group.group_id,
                "description": ip.group.description,
                "ranges": [],
            }
        group_map[group_id]["ranges"].append(ip.address)

    json_response["objects"] = list(group_map.values())
    return json_response

def create_ip_file():
    try:
        base_dir = "C://Users/Steven/Desktop"
        json_filename = "blocklist.json"
        csv_filename = "blocklist.csv"

        # Create JSON file
        json_full_path = os.path.join(base_dir, json_filename)
        with open(json_full_path, "w") as f:
            json_data = get_ip_list_json()
            f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
        
        # Convert JSON data to DataFrame
        objects = json_data["objects"]
        data_for_csv = []
        for obj in objects:
            for ip in obj["ranges"]:
                data_for_csv.append({
                    "name": obj["name"],
                    "id": obj["id"],
                    "description": obj["description"],
                    "ip_range": ip
                })

        df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_csv)

        # Create CSV file
        csv_full_path = os.path.join(base_dir, csv_filename)
        df.to_csv(csv_full_path, index=False)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


Thanks for that, fixed my issue, the only change I have made just as a personal choice was adding this "blockedlist = BlockedList.objects.all()" and then just did for obj in blockedlist, and then reference my object in model with obj.address. Will put in an edit to show my change.
